# Changing the popup-menu of a NodeTree

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform

This is about a Netbeans 7.1 platform app. Following  [this tutorial](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-nodesapi2.html) I added the following  to the code of my NodetreeTopComponent, in order to change the context-menu:

```
 @Override
public Action[] getActions() {
    return new Action[] {new MyAction()};
}

private static class MyAction extends AbstractAction {

   public MyAction () {
    putValue (NAME, "New Whatever");
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    NewWhateverTopComponent nk = new NewWhateverTopComponent();
    nk.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Unfortunately, this does exactly nothing. Right-clicking any node in my tree i still get just the default Menu (Copy, Properties). What have i overseen?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...I added the following to the code of my NodetreeTopComponent...

You need to override the `getActions()` method of your **Node** not your `TopComponent`. In the tutorial that you linked to refer to the section titled [Actions and Nodes](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-nodesapi2.html#actions). Step one states:

> Override the getActions() method of **EventNode** as follows

I believe this is where you've gone askew.

Comment: You're welcome and good luck. The Node API is one of the more challenging NetBeans APIs to master.